# Retrieve invited users with Telegram Bot API

Tags: node.js, telegram, psql, telegram-bot, telegraf

I have a Telegram channel and a Telegram bot using Node.js and PSQL. With a command (for example /how), I need to return to the user the number of user which has been invited to the channel by this user (and has joined).
How can I retrieve this list of users ?

Answer (score 0):

If by "invited" you mean users who sent others a link to the channel then Telegram API does not provide such functionality.

However, channel administrators can add users to the channel and those should be sent as regular [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) updates with `new_chat_members` field set, all you have to do is log those updates to the database and then fetch it with your command.